# ZMQ Publisher Side Filtering in C

Tags: c, publish-subscribe, zeromq

I am trying to implement a `PUB-SUB` using `ZMQ 3.2` in C.

I am able to do filtering at subscriber level.
I am using this:

```
rc = zmq_setsockopt (subscriber, ZMQ_SUBSCRIBE, filter, strlen (filter));
```

Now I want to implement this feature at the publisher side. Means suppose I have some message to publish, the publisher should only publish when it has my filter string in that message. How can I do this? Any API to support this in `ZMQ 3.2`?

Comment: why do you want to implement extra publisher-side filtering?  Filters are already evaluated on the publisher-side in zmq 3.2 (messages that do not match subscriptions are never sent).

Comment: Yes, I have been reading about this but still am unable to execute this... Can you suggest a link which has an example to do the same?

Comment: Sure, the line in your question above. When a subscriber sets a subscription, it is sent to the publisher where it is evaluated.  *All* subscription filters are publisher-side in zmq 3.

Comment: Hi Minrk, A small gist of my code:
Publisher:

zmq::socket_t pub (context, ZMQ_XPUB);
pub.bind("tcp://*:5556");

  (zipcode == 1111) ? zipcode = 2222 : zipcode = 1111;
  memcpy ((void *) MsgBroadcast.data (), zipcode, 6);
  pub.send(MsgBroadcast);
  

----
Subscriber:


 zmq::socket_t sub (context, ZMQ_XSUB);

 sub.connect("tcp://localhost:5556");
 
 // Subscribe to zipcode, default 1111
 char *filter = "01111";

 sub.setsockopt(ZMQ_SUBSCRIBE, filter, strlen (filter));

 sub.recv(&reply);

 


Now my client only receives data which has 1111 in it.

Comment: Now my client only receives data which has 1111 in it.
Do you mean to say that if I am using XPUB and XSUB, this filtering is actually taking place at the publisher side and not the subscriber side?

If this is not the case, how do I notify the publisher that this subscriber needs only this kind of data?

Answer (score 10):

*moving into an answer*

ZeroMQ subscriptions are always evaluated publisher-side in versions ≥ 3.0.  Just use plain old PUB/SUB, no reason to use XPUB / XSUB.  When you do `sub.setsockopt(zmq.SUBSCRIBE, 'topic')`, the SUB actually tells the PUB about the subscription, and the PUB will only send messages matching current subscriptions.

Comment: Thanks a ton mate... made my job much easier.. :)

Comment: Anyone know documentation link for this behavior?